# 502-Web server received and invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: sql, reporting-services

we have two application servers with load balancer and one report server. When we tried to retrieve one week of data using our domain name, we cannot able to retrieve the records and got the error as in the image. However, if we retrieve using the application server IP address, the records can retrieve. Any idea why does this happen?  Please advise. [Please check error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc9sZ.png)

Comment: Hi there, try to be a little bit more specific about what's going on on the server side. Provide logs and code snippets to provide the implementation on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi i have modified the questions to be more specific.